# dsPIC33 Timer sometimes jumps to high values

Tags: pic, timer, mplabx, timeout

I have an issue using dsPIC33EV128GM106 32 bits Timer2 in a while() statement with a timeout.
Basically what I am trying to do is communicate with a Power Supply through UART2.

After sending an order I wait for the 68bit PSU answer which ends with "0x0D".
I read the RX buffer until I get to the "0x0D" character **OR** if the timeout (set to 100ms) triggers.

**This code works nearly all the time but sometimes the function ZPLUS_waitResponse() exits with code 2.**

I used the MPLABX variable watch to check the value stored in `buff*` and I can see that the `buff*` stops filling somewhere in the middle of the 68bit message. I decided to perform some checks with the oscilloscope but I can see the entire PSU answer of 68 bits with 0x0D at the end.

I then decided to look for a timeout condition and realized that **Timer2_Counter_32bitsGet() sometimes returns a strangely high value. Let's say a regularly-spaced sequence like that : "1000, 1030, 1060, 1090 and then suddenly 43445566" ... which causes a timeout issue!**

**Again, this phenomenon appears around 1 time out of hundreds. Most of the time `buff[]` stores the complete 68bits sequences without any timeout issue.**

Timer2 code was generated using MCC and looks like this (following code only shows portions of interest):

```
void TMR2_Initialize (void)
{
    //TMR3 0; 
    TMR3 = 0x00;
    //PR3 65535; 
    PR3 = 0xFFFF;
    //TMR2 0; 
    TMR2 = 0x00;
    //Period = 31.9us; PR2 65535; 
    PR2 = 0xFFFF;
    //TCKPS 1:256; T32 32 Bit; TON enabled; TSIDL disabled; TCS FOSC/2; TGATE disabled; 
    T2CON = 0x8038;
    
    tmr2_obj.timerElapsed = false;
}

void TMR2_Tasks_32BitOperation( void )
{
    /* Check if the Timer Interrupt/Status is set */
    if(IFS0bits.T3IF)
    {
        tmr2_obj.count++;
        tmr2_obj.timerElapsed = true;
        IFS0bits.T3IF = false;
    }
}

uint32_t TMR2_Counter32BitGet( void )
{
    uint32_t countVal = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    uint16_t countValUpper;
    uint16_t countValLower;

    countValLower = TMR2;
    countValUpper = TMR3HLD;

    /* get the current counter value and return it */
    countVal = (((uint32_t)countValUpper<<16)| countValLower );

    return( countVal );
}

uint32_t tempsEnMs(void)
{
    uint32_t temp=0;
    float temp_en_ms=0; 
    uint32_t temp2=0;
    
    temp = TMR2_Counter32BitGet(); //1 LSB = 31,98655 us // attention dans MCC beug
    temp_en_ms = (float)(temp) * 0.03198655;
    temp2 = (uint32_t) roundf(temp_en_ms);
    
    return temp2;
}
```

The function which causes the problem looks like this:

```
uint8_t ZPLUS_waitResponse(uint8_t *buff)
{
    uint32_t timing_tab[68] = {0}; // for debug
    
    uint32_t initialTime = tempsEnMs();
    //_LATE14 ^= 1; // for debug
    
    uint8_t index=0;
    uint32_t timing = initialTime;
    
    uint8_t temp;
    
    while ((timing-initialTime) < ZPLUS_TIMOUT_in_ms)
    {
        timing = tempsEnMs();
        //timing_tab[index] = timing; // for debug
        timing_tab[index] = TMR2_Counter32BitGet(); // for debug
        if (pfZPLUS_lib.UART2_IsRxReady() == 1 && index<=67)
        {
            temp = pfZPLUS_lib.UART2_Read();
            
            if (temp ==  0x0D) 
                return 1;
            else 
            {
               buff[index] = temp; 
               index++;
            }
            
        } 
        
    }
    //_LATE14 ^= 1; // for debug
    Nop();Nop();Nop(); // for debug
    return 2;    
}
```

This function is called by another function:

```
void ZPLUS_readAll(TypeZPLUS *ID,float *voltage, float *setVoltage, float *current, float *setCurrent, int16_t *statusReg, int16_t *faultReg, bool currentSup100A )
{    
    pfZPLUS_lib.UART2_Write('S');
    pfZPLUS_lib.UART2_Write('T');
    pfZPLUS_lib.UART2_Write('T');  
    pfZPLUS_lib.UART2_Write('?');      
    pfZPLUS_lib.UART2_Write(0x0D);
    
    char buff[68]={0};
    char test = 0;
    test = ZPLUS_waitResponse(&buff[0]);  //@todo : a voir si on exploite ou pas le timout2);
    
    if(test==2){
        _LATE14 ^= 1; // sortie_led_toggle()
        Nop();Nop();Nop();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Datasheet has set of steps to configure timer in chapter 12.0, you do not follow it. Not sure, cannot see it immediately, but should timer be stopped before restarting (may it be a rollover of the MSW while you initialize value with timer running)?

Comment: Timer2 is set to ON with TON bit in T2CON register. This is set in the Timer2_initialize() function which is called in SYSTEM_Initialize() before the main while(1) loop. Timer2 is then only read when needed, not written. I will see what's inside chapter 12 but timer seems OK most of the time ...